# Wrong hibernate SQL query: ElementCollection included as column

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have this field in an Entity class, which a collection of String's:

```
...
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm")
@JoinColumn(name="wifi_network_config_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private ArrayList<String> authAlgorithm = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getAuthAlgorithm() {
    return authAlgorithm;
}

public void setAuthAlgorithm(ArrayList<String> authAlgorithm) {
    this.authAlgorithm = authAlgorithm;
}
...
```

When I use HibernateTemplate.find("from wifi_network_config") the query below is generated & causes SQLGrammarException as the column corresponding to the field 'authAlgorithm' is not in the database table. Since authAlgorithm is a collection, it should not be included in the query.

```
2012-02-16 10:11:56,365 WARN - <SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22>
2012-02-16 10:11:56,366 ERROR - <Unknown column 'wifinetwor0_.authAlgorithm' in 'field list'>
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select wifinetwor0_.id as id0_, wifinetwor0_.ssid as ssid0_, wifinetwor0_.priority as priority0_, wifinetwor0_.auth_algorithms as auth4_0_, wifinetwor0_.group_cipher as group5_0_, wifinetwor0_.key_management as key6_0_, wifinetwor0_.pairwise_cipher as pairwise7_0_, wifinetwor0_.protocol as protocol0_, wifinetwor0_.vpn_type as vpn9_0_, wifinetwor0_.vpn_url as vpn10_0_, wifinetwor0_.authAlgorithm as authAlg11_0_ from wifi_network_config wifinetwor0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
```

Database is MySql. This works in a small test program that's run against hsqldb.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Changing field declatation to:

    **@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="wifi_network_config_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private ArrayList<String> authAlgorithm = new ArrayList<String>();**

did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You may not declare a persistent collection as an `ArrayList`. You must use the interface instead: `List`. Hibernate needs to replace your actual collection by a Hibernate-specific collection (which implements List).

It's a good practice in general to program to interfaces rather than implementations. When using Hibernate or JPA, it's madatory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did have List, but it caused a different issue. I'm using ArrayList to get around that. The info about that other issue is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298946/hibernate-session-factory-not-able-to-resolve-enum-type-for-field-thats-a-list)

Comment: It caused exactly the same issue, I think: instead of storing the list in a realated table, it stores it as a serialized byte array in a single column. Check your database.

Comment: The database has the related table set up. It's just that hibernate is refusing to use it. I doubt that it stores all the elements in the set in a single column. In the standalone test program that uses @ElementCollection, hibernate does generate the queries to read the related table to populate the set. It is breaking in a web application - may be the application environment has something to do with it.

Comment: You can't use a concrete  collection type (ArrayList) as the type of a collection of elements or as the type of an association. That's for sure. I don't see how the same code would do two very different things on two different environments. Why don't you tell us what happens when you use a List rather than an ArrayList? Why are you ignoring answers?

Comment: I'm not ignoring answers. I might have misunderstood your previous response. You are of course right about ArrayList not working as the type of collection elements. When I use List instead of ArrayList I get the exception described in the other post for which the link is in my first comment above (which is why I tried ArrayList). Did you check that link? I tried ArrayList in the working program. It produced the output in the next comment. Note that it's not the exact same code used inthe two cases. I will use the working code as is in the web application, and post the results in a few days.

Comment: Output from program that used to work after changing List to ArrayList: **1156 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.vaannila.student.Student, setter method of property: courses
1172 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: java.util.ArrayList, actual value: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag**